# Java Swing: Force focus on child Panel/Frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
private void jBtnAboutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    jPanel_About.setSize(300, 300);
    jPanel_About.setVisible(true);
}
```

How can I make User unable to select the main jFrame where jBtn_About is located while the About Panel pop-up?

Also, the code does show a new panel but it's created at top left corner of display. How can i allign it to be created in middle of the main jFrame?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JDialog (as modal window) instead of jPanel_About.
For JDialog you can use setLocation to place it in desired position.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I force focus on the current windows since It can be troublemaking to let user access main Frame while a windows (says, Add or Modify diaglog is poping-up)

Comment: JDialog (in modal mode) don't let user to access main frame while JDialog is visible.

Comment: @qkhanhpro See [how to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)